# How can we disable past dates from date input field in admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, datepicker

I am using below code to add date field in one of the admin forms.

```
$fieldset->addField('newsletter_date', 'date', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('masters')->__('Send At'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'newsletter_date',
    'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm',
    'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
    'time' =>   'true'
));
```

How I can disable past dates from newsletter_date field?

Answer (score 2):

You can't out of the box. But you can implement your own validation based on Magento's `js/prototype/validation.js`.

[Inchoo has a good blogpost about this.](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

After Magentos `validation.js` is added you can just add your own and then use the CSS class to validate the field right before the form submit.

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid Gmail address. For example johndoe@gmail.com.', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@gmail\.com)$/i.test(v)
})
```

Example is copied from the inchoo article, I'm not good with JS, so I'll let the implementation of `$date > now()` up to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using below method one can disable past dates from Magento admin form

```
            $datefield = $fieldset->addField('custom_date', 'date', array(
                    'label'        => Mage::helper('order')->__('Date'),
                    'name'         => 'custom_date',
                    'time'         => true,
                    'image'        => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                    "class"        => "required-entry validate-date",
                    "required"     => true,
                    'format'       => $dateFormatIso
                )); 

            $datefield->setAfterElementHtml("<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            //<![CDATA[
                Calendar.setup({
                    inputField: 'custom_date',
                    ifFormat: '%m/%e/%Y',
                    showsTime: false,
                    button: 'custom_date_trig',
                    align: 'Bl',
                    singleClick : true,
                disableFunc: function(date) {
                    var now= new Date();
                    if(date.getFullYear()<now.getFullYear()){ return true; }
                    if(date.getFullYear()==now.getFullYear()){ if(date.getMonth()<now.getMonth()){ return true; } }
                    if(date.getMonth()== now.getMonth()){ if(date.getDate()<now.getDate()){ return true; } }
                    return date.getDay() === 0; // Disabled Sunday
                },
                });
            //]]>
            </script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will help this. This way i was able to add the datepicker to my field and disabled whatever days I wanted

```
$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('yourid');
$form = new Varien_Data_Form();
.....
$fieldset->addField('newsletter_date', 'text', [
    'label'     => Mage::helper('masters')->__('Send At'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'newsletter_date',
]);
```

and add this after:

```
        $form->getElement('newsletter_date')->setAfterElementHtml("<script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[
                 Calendar.setup({
                    inputField : 'yourid_newsletter_date',
                    ifFormat : '%Y-%m-%d',
                    button : 'call_date',
                    align : 'Bl',
                    singleClick : true,
                    disableFunc: function(date)  {
                        var now = new Date();

                        if(date.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()) { return true; }
                        if(date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() < now.getMonth()) { return true; }
                        if(date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() < now.getDate()) { return true; }
                    }
                  });
        //]]>
       </script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldset->addField('newsletter_date', 'date', array(
'label'     => Mage::helper('masters')->__('Send At'),
'class'     => 'required-entry',
'required'  => true,
'name'      => 'newsletter_date',
'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm',
'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
'time' =>   'true',
disableFunc: function(date) {
//disable previous day in datepicker
var now= new Date();
if(date.getFullYear()<now.getFullYear())
{
return true;
}
if(date.getFullYear()==now.getFullYear())
{
if(date.getMonth()<now.getMonth())
{
return true;
}
}
if(date.getMonth()==now.getMonth())
{
if(date.getDate()<now.getDate())
{
return true;
}
}
}
```

));

just try this code i'm not sure if it works for you but it works for me