# How to validate email Domain name in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento the email check only for "@" and "." validation but it is not validating the domain name.
For example : abc@xyz.in  is been accepted in magento.
Please help me to validate the domain names
Thank You

Comment: Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71586/how-can-we-disable-past-dates-from-date-input-field-in-admin/71594#71594

Comment: can you tell me which types are domain allowed?

Comment: The domain names should be validate on server side , i am not storing any domain names in my database. Can i use isemail in my magento project?

Comment: Its not duplicate question plz check the question